# How to sudo bash keywords like [[

Tags: bash

I want to test if a file exists. I don't have access to the directory without `sudo`.

```
if sudo [[ -f ~otheruser/.ssh/id_rsa ]]; then echo 'asdf'; fi
```

returns  `sudo: [[: command not found`.

```
if sudo [ -f ~otheruser/.ssh/id_rsa ]; then echo 'asdf'; fi
```

or

```
if sudo test -f ~otheruser/.ssh/id_rsa; then echo 'asdf'; fi
```

both work.

I know this is because `[[` is a bash keyword, while `test` and `[` are builtins, meaning that we can do `a='['; $a -f "~/.ssh/id_rsa" ]` but not `a='[['; $a -f "~/.ssh/id_rsa" ]]` among other things. Is this another limitation? You're just not allowed to sudo bash keywords?

(All my information comes from SO answers because that's what google returns; sorry if there was a better spot to look.)

Comment: Is this for general interest or because you've heard that `[[` is better than `[`? The latter advice does not apply when you have to go through `sudo` and a nested bash command, so it would be much better to use `sudo [` or `sudo test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `[[` is Bash syntax, you can:

```
if sudo bash -c '[[ -f "some-file" ]]'; then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```

---

`sudo [` and `sudo test` works because they are also external commands:

```
/usr/bin/[
/usr/bin/test
```

Comment: If you change it to double quotes (`~otheruser` won't expand in `' '`), I'll accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: single quotes are better here then u don't need to backslash escape the inner double quotes.

Comment: bash also understand `~USER`.

Comment: try it. `bash -c 'echo ~root'` outputs `/root` for me.

Comment: @jeremysprofile Keep in mind that there are two levels of expansion at play now. A value can be expanded by your script's shell or `sudo`s shell independently of one another. This is one of the reasons why you would avoid this kind of code IRL.

Comment: *"Bash does NOT understand ~USER within single quotes."* -- `~USER` also does not work in double quotes, try `echo "~root"`.

Comment: @pynexj, you were right. I apologize. Thanks for your help with this